# Python: Adjective Synsets in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is there a method in NLTK to be able to find certain adjective attributes that describe the word? For example, if I typed in the word "Skyscraper", attributes such as 'tall', 'structured', etc. would appear. I'm more so interested in the reverse, where if I type in the word 'tall' then it will list the semantic relations with other words.

I believe the attribute method on NLTK is meant for this, but it doesn't work particularly the way I described above and this is the code that I'm using for it:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
synsets = wn.synsets('skyscraper')
print[str(syns.attributes()) for syns in synsets]
```

I've tried using the part_meronyms and attributes methods, but this doesn't always result the adjective attributes of a word. I know of other Python tools that would allow me to do this, but I would prefer to use only NLTK as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using purely NLTK, you can achieve this as a two-step process, with your own functions.

**Basic Idea**

- Step 1. Find all meaningful **collocations** for your target word ("skyscraper" or "tall")
- Step 2. For the adjectives identified in those collocations that are of interest to you, parse the POS to get the semantic relations.

For Step 1. this [SO question on Scoring bigrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683588/understanding-nltk-collocation-scoring-for-bigrams-and-trigrams) has defs that are very relevant. You'll have to tweak the `BigramAssocMeasures` to your problem. (It uses the brown corpus, but you can use many others.)

For Step 2. you could use something like **`pos_tag()`** or even **`Tree.parse()`** to get the associations that you are looking for to your target adjective.

For a (simpler) and alternative approach, [this link](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html) has examples of **`text.similar()`** that should be relevant.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for NLTK to have some form of built in semantic relation through WordNet, like how hypernyms/hyponyms works, but I can definitely see how this would be applicable to my question